# Why do I get different results modelling the same dataset in R using faintr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rstudio-server

I used the following code:

```
fit <- brms::brm(
 formula = expected_response ~ speaker * metaphor, 
 data    = dat_forStats,
 family  = bernoulli(link = "logit")
 )

faintr::compare_groups(
 fit,
 higher = speaker == "reliable",
 lower  = speaker == "unreliable"
 )
```

The results only differ slightly from each other: sometimes 0.9165, sometimes 0.9038, 0.9035, 0.9052 or on the latest run,0.9052.

Because I am not using a random variable, I did not set a seed. Should I set one anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a seed is always a good practice to ensure reproducibility. If you don't set a seed, the random number generator used in the fitting process will generate a different sequence of random numbers each time you run the code. This can cause the results to vary slightly from one run to another, as you have observed.

```
set.seed(123)
```

Comment: I don't have a random number generator in my code, as said in my post

Comment: And even after setting a seed, I get different results every time.

Comment: Probably than has to do with the design of the package brms. I am myself not familiar with the source code of this package. Good luck with your problem :)